# Need a word for someone not acknowledging what you are saying, and who attempts to put you in a bad light

Tags: terminology

Word for:  when a person you are dealing with does not acknowledge what you are saying but rather, goes on  the attack and attempts to present you in a bad light, such as diversionary tactics

Comment: Maybe ***ad hominem***? Please add a few specific & concrete examples to your question (you can [edit] it to do so).

Comment: It sounds like basic disrespect with a variety of manifestations of that disrespect.  If you could be more specific on the behavior and possible motivation of that person, and possibly a sentence with a blank where that word should be, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to name the person, the situation, the attack, or something else? I can't tell whether I like the answer given, or even whether I should respond to the question.

Comment: It's redirection, but I don't know what word would be used.  Is "ad hominem" a diversionary tactic?  It certainly describes what he is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You might call their rhetoric an **"argumentum ad hominem".** When used preemptively even before you even have a chance to say a word, it's called **"poisoning the well"**.

> - An **ad hominem** (Latin for "to the man" or "to the person"), short for **argumentum ad hominem**, is an attack on an argument made by attacking the character, motive, or other attribute of the person making the argument, rather than attacking the argument directly. When used inappropriately, it is a logical fallacy in which a claim or argument is dismissed on the basis of some irrelevant fact or supposition about the author or the person being criticized.
>     [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem)
> - **Poisoning the well** (or attempting to poison the well) is a fallacy where adverse information about a target is preemptively presented to an audience, with the intention of discrediting or ridiculing everything that the target person is about to say. Poisoning the well can be a special case of argumentum ad hominem, and the term was first used with this sense by John Henry Newman in his work Apologia Pro Vita Sua (1864).  [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well)